# How to scale system font in SwiftUI to support Dynamic Type?

Tags: ios, swiftui, dynamic-type-feature

In UIKit, I can change a UILabel's font size like this to support dynamic type using the system font:

```
UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16))
```

Am I mistaken or is there no way to do such thing in SwiftUI?
Can I only use the default font styles .title, etc. if I want to use the system font but also support Dynamic Type?

[This solution](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-dynamic-type-with-a-custom-font) from HackingWithSwift seems to only work with custom fonts, right?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following approach works (tested with Xcode 11.2.1 / iOS 13.2.2)

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!") // direct text .font
        .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
}
```

as well as for view-based modifier

```
VStack {
    Text("Hello, World!")
}
.font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
```

Comment: Welp, I tried that as well, but only trusted the preview using:
`.environment(\.sizeCategory, .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge)`
I guess that's a bug? Using .font(.title) the preview displays the scaled size.

At runtime your answer works, thanks!

Comment: If the user changes the text size, the displayed text does not dynamically update.

Comment: @EdwardBrey I have the same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: @Ricardo, you can combine this with scale metric. Next should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607605/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi: You have to include the environment variable anywhere to make that work. Example: @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory

Answer (score 5):

As long as you have

```swift
@Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
```

somewhere in the hierarchy of files loaded, `.font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))` will change when the system font size changes.

The view modifier @Mokkun posted above works because it includes the environment variable `sizeCategory`.

It will also work if you put the environment variable `sizeCategory` at the top of any SwiftUI view, and then use `UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(...)` directly. Like this:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentViewSheet: View {

    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world")
            .font(Font.system(size: UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: 16)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a `ViewModifier` and a `View` extension just like in the [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-dynamic-type-with-a-custom-font) article you mentioned, but that uses the system font instead.

```
struct ScaledFont: ViewModifier {
    // From the article:
    // Asks the system to provide the current size category from the
    // environment, which determines what level Dynamic Type is set to.
    // The trick is that we don’t actually use it – we don’t care what the
    // Dynamic Type setting is, but by asking the system to update us when
    // it changes our UIFontMetrics code will be run at the same time,
    // causing our font to scale correctly.
    @Environment(\.sizeCategory) var sizeCategory
    var size: CGFloat
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        let scaledSize = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledValue(for: size)
        return content.font(.system(size: scaledSize))
    }
}

extension View {
    func scaledFont(size: CGFloat) -> some View {
        return self.modifier(ScaledFont(size: size))
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
var body: some View {
    Text("Hello, World!").scaledFont(size: 18)
}
```

You can use the Environment Overrides panel on Xcode 12 to test it.

Comment: You declared `sizeCategory` but you're not using it anywhere.

Comment: @andrewz that is intentional. From the linked article "That (`sizeCategory`) asks the system to provide the current size category from the environment, which determines what level Dynamic Type is set to. The trick is that we don’t actually use it..."

Answer (score 0):

From iOS 14, SwiftUI supports Dynamic Type as:

```
 Text("Large Title")
   .font(
       .custom(
           "Your CustomFont",
           size: 34,
           relativeTo: .largeTitle
       )
   )
```