# Preventing a Text view from breaking when the font size is increased in SwiftUI (Dynamic type / accessibility)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hstack

I have a few views in an HStack which gives me a view like this

[image: SwiftUI HStack]

There are 3 images and 2 Text views in here

My goal is to support graceful dynamic text / font scaling for larger text sizes, that is scaling the images and the text views.

This works for the most part:

[image: HStack SwiftUI Dynamic Text Accessibility HStack]

[image: HStack SwiftUI Dynamic Text Accessibility]

My issue arises on really large sizes and with the text, the text itself seems break because it is within an HStack

[image: HStack SwiftUI Dynamic font large text]

What I desire is for the 19.5 to be in 1 line and the the 20 to be on another line rather than the 19.5 breaking - is this possible ?

I've tried things like applying `.lineLimit()` of `1` and `nil` to the text as I saw in some answers but that didn't work.

I've also tried applying `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` to the text to no avail.

I use `@ScaledMetric` outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607605/1619193) to scale the image.

Happy to share any code, however, it is just a basic HStack with 3 image views and two text views.

Comment: Did you try `Text("19.5") + Text("/") + Text("20")` instead of `HStack`?

Comment: @lazarevzubov - I did give this a shot but it did not give me the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try applying `. minimumScaleFactor` in combination with `.scaledToFit` to the `HStack` with the `Text` elements:

```swift
private var target: some View {
    Image(systemName: "target")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .foregroundStyle(.red)
        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
}

var body: some View {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        target
        target
        target
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            Text("19.5")
                .foregroundStyle(.yellow)
            Text("/")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
            Text("20")
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
        .padding(.leading, 10)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
        .scaledToFit()
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(.black)
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This solution works really well for the most part. The only thing I notice is that at a certain point, the image keeps scaling and then the text starts shrinking. So I applied your `minimumScaleFactor` and `.scaledToFit` to the outer `HStack` which almost gives the desirable result. The only minor issue now is that at the max size - the `19.5` becomes slightly smaller than the `/` and `20`. Not sure if there is a simple way to ensure they are always the same size.

Comment: @ShawnFrank Pleased to hear you're getting nearer to a solution. I would suggest keeping the `scaledToFit` on the inner `HStack` and then find another way to resolve the issue of the image scaling. You could submit a new post if you need help (with a minimal reproducible example to demonstrate the issue).